# Unknow grant_type status code 401 TrustPilot email invitation authentification

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, trustpilot

I am trying to use TrustPilot API to send email invitation for reviews. No matter what i do the result is unknown grant_type. The documentation says that the grant_type should be set to "password" in order to get the token so i can use to send the invitation with the proper options.

```
export const inviteBuyer = async (email, orderNumber) => {
  const base64 = new Base64();
  const secrets = base64.encode('APIKEY:APISECRET');
  const authOptions = {
    data: 'grant_type=password&username=myemail&password=mypassword',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + secrets,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
  };

  const authUrl = 'https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken';

  try {
    const getIdentity = await HTTP.call('POST', authUrl, authOptions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  const options = {
    headers: {
      token: getIdentity.access_token,
    },
    parameters: {
      consumerEmail: email,
      consumerName: 'John Doe',
      referenceNumber: orderNumber,
      locale: 'en',
      senderEmail: 'OurEMail', // potentiellmeent
      serviceReviewInvitation: {
        // preferredSendTime: '2013-09-07T13:37:00',
        // redirectUri: 'http://trustpilot.com',
        tags: ['buyer'],
        // templateId: '507f191e810c19729de860ea',
      },
    },
  };

  try {
    const resp = await HTTP.call(
      'POST',
      'https://invitations-api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/business-units/OurBusinessUnitId/email-invitations',
      options
    );
    console.dir(resp);
  } catch (err) {}
  console.log(err);
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending the body correctly? I don't recognize whatever HTTP library you are using. What you're sending seems reasonable, but many http clients will use the term 'body' not 'payload', for example.

Comment: A missing body _could_ definitely cause that error.

Comment: i tried body and every name you could imagine :p
it is a meteor project and i am using the http package, that's why the code requests are like that ( sorry for the late answer)

Comment: A quick look at the documentation of the Meteor HTTP client: https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html. The word 'payload' does not exist on this page. Don't guess, rely on the docs!

Comment: i did use data,body, params, every appelation xD
the problem is that the documentation of trustpilot says it is payload.
That is not the issue...

Comment: I am stuck on this and couldn't find any solution. I tried the exact same code for someone who got the authentification correctly but same issue ...

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If you use the Meteor HTTP client, you need to follow their documentation. If you say you tried all of the above, edit your question to match Meteor's documentation.

Comment: Maybe trustpilot calls the body 'payload' but that doesn't meant that meteor will also support this. 'Payload' will likely be ignored. So fix your question, run your code again and share the results.

Comment: Saw your edit. I don't think `data` is correct either, because `data` (according to the docs) will be JSON serialized automatically, and this endpoint does not expect JSON. It seems that the correct keyword here is `content`. (See the meteor docs)

Comment: i did changed it to data run the code, changed it to body and run the code, changed it to content and run the code...

Comment: Ok, what result are you getting with `content`?  Same error, or something different?

Comment: the auth is working now but the next one is not
let me check ( i just replied to not make u wait .. )

Comment: There ya go. Good luck!

Comment: can i ask another question ?

Comment: Well, since this has been solved.. Maybe just open a new stack overflow question?

Comment: i will mark this as solved but i need to finish this in 30 minutes or i will be in trouble lol.
After i get the acces_token, i am using it to send the invitation. I have a problem. If im not taking much of your time, let me try something and then get back to you

Comment: If you open an new question on stack overflow, feel free to link me so I can take a look!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101827/typeerror-the-first-argument-must-be-of-type-string-or-an-instance-of-buffer-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question used a `payload` key for specifying the body, and later on `data`.

However, to send a raw HTTP request body with the Meteor HTTP client, `content` must be used:

```js
  const authOptions = {
    content: 'grant_type=password&username=myemail&password=mypassword',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + secrets,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
  };
```